# Store associative array of strings with length as keys

Tags: java, string, collections, associative-array

I have this input:

```
5
it
your
reality
real
our
```

First line is number of strings comming after. And i should store it this way (pseudocode):

```
associative_array = [ 2 => ['it'], 3 => ['our'], 4 => ['real', 'your'], 7 => ['reality']]
```

As you can see the keys of associative array are the length of strings stored in inner array.
So how can i do this in java ? I came from php world, so if you will compare it with php, it will be very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

djechlin already posted a better version, but here's a complete standalone example using just JDK classes:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;    
   public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String firstLine = reader.readLine();
            int numOfRowsToFollow = Integer.parseInt(firstLine);
            Map<Integer,Set<String>> stringsByLength = new HashMap<>(numOfRowsToFollow); //worst-case size
            for (int i=0; i<numOfRowsToFollow; i++) {
                String line = reader.readLine();
                int length = line.length();
                Set<String> alreadyUnderThatLength = stringsByLength.get(length); //int boxed to Integer
                if (alreadyUnderThatLength==null) {
                    alreadyUnderThatLength = new HashSet<>();
                    stringsByLength.put(length, alreadyUnderThatLength);
                }
                alreadyUnderThatLength.add(line);
            }
            System.out.println("results: "+stringsByLength);
        }
    }
```

its output looks like this:

```
3
bob
bart
brett
results: {4=[bart], 5=[brett], 3=[bob]}
```

Comment: Why use "new HashMap<>(numOfRowsToFollow)" ? you think it will save memory ?

Comment: I think this one solves the full problem being asked. My only comment (though he doesn't say this explicitly) is that his example shows the keys in ascending order. You can get that for free by changing your HashMap to a TreeMap, I think.

Comment: @kirugan: force of habit. it wont affect the results if you dont provide an initial size (as java collections grow/shrink by themselves) but sometimes if you know a collection is going to be extremely large/small in advance you can save the memory shuffle involved in letting it grow/shrink all the way there by itself

Comment: @GSP : it doesnt sort anything, thats just how i happened to type things in

Comment: Technically, if you're going to give a size for the Hashmap, you should make it bigger than the actual number of entries. By default Hashmaps get resized, not when you hit the number of entries given, but when you hit some percentage of this, I think the default is 75%. Also, bear in mind that values in a Hashmap are, well, hashed. If you're Hashmap has size, say, 5, that doesn't mean that 5 entries will fit neatly. You will almost surely get hash collisions mucking up processing. Better to give some spare room to minimize the collisions.

Answer (score 3):

```
MultiMap<Integer, String> m = new MultiHashMap<Integer, String>();

for(String item : originalCollection) {
    m.put(item.length(), item);
}
```

Comment: There are multiple values for the same key.

Comment: what is original collection ?

Comment: this code is using the MultiMap class from the apache commons collections library - http://commons.apache.org/collections/

Comment: @kirugan it's your original collection.

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't have associative arrays. But it does have Hashmaps, which mostly accomplishes the same goal. In your case, you can have multiple values for any given key. So what you could do is make each entry in the Hashmap an array or a collection of some kind. ArrayList is a likely choice. That is:

```
Hashmap<Integer,ArrayList<String>> words=new HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<String>>();
```

I'm not going to go through the code to read your list from a file or whatever, that's a different question. But just to give you the idea of how the structure would work, suppose we could hard-code the list. We could do it something like this:

```
ArrayList<String> set=new ArrayList<String)();
set.add("it");
words.put(Integer.valueOf(2), set);
set.clear();
set.add("your");
set.add("real");
words.put(Integer.valueOf(4), set);
```

Etc.

```
In practice, you probably would regularly be adding words to an existing set. I often do that like this:

void addWord(String word)
{
  Integer key=Integer.valueOf(word.length());
  ArrayList<String> set=words.get(key);
  if (set==null)
  {
    set=new ArrayList<String>();
    words.put(key,set);
  }
  // either way we now have a set
  set.add(word);
}
```

Side note: I often see programmers end a block like this by putting "set" back into the Hashmap, i.e. "words.put(key,set)" at the end. This is unnecessary: it's already there. When you get "set" from the Hashmap, you're getting a reference, not a copy, so any updates you make are just "there", you don't have to put it back.

Disclaimer: This code is off the top of my head. No warranties expressed or implied. I haven't written any Java in a while so I may have syntax errors or wrong function names. :-)

Answer (score 0):

As your key appears to be small integer, you could use a list of lists.  In this case the simplest solution is to use a MultiMap like

```
Map<Integer, Set<String>> stringByLength = new LinkedHashMap<>();

for(String s: strings) {
   Integer len = s.length();
   Set<String> set = stringByLength.get(s);
   if(set == null)
        stringsByLength.put(len, set = new LinkedHashSet<>());
   set.add(s);
}
```

Comment: some example please, as you know in php there is not so much collections than in java, and i`m newbie in it

Answer (score 0):

```
private HashMap<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();

void addStringToMap(String s) {
    int length = s.length();
    if (map.get(length) == null) {
        map.put(length, new ArrayList<String>());
    }
    map.get(length).add(s);
}
```